# FindMyDevice without having access to the device

Tags: security

This is a bizarre question to have to ask but: how am I supposed to use FindMyDevice if it requires my device to confirm it's me who's trying to find my device?

I recently lost my phone (I luckily got it back another way) and absolutely couldn't get FindMyDevice to work.

Here is what I attempted:

1. start FindMyDevice on my friend's phone
2. sign in as a guest
3. now I'm getting "2-step verification" displayed on my friend's phone and im getting a push notification my own phone (which I didn't have access to)
4. when I pressed "Try another way" I got four options:

   - Tap yes on your phone or tablet, which I couldn't
   - Use your phone or tablet to get a security code, which I couldn't
   - Get a verification code at my , which I couldn't
   - Try account recovery, which sends just yet another push notification to my phone, which I couldn't confirm either.

Comment: Find My Device can be accessed from [the web](https://www.google.com/android/find?u=0), but this is assuming that you already have a browser that is logged in to your Google account.

Comment: @AndrewT Okay, but the app is useless? Or do I need the app on my phone so the browser can find it?

Comment: The app can be useful if you have multiple Android devices connected to the same Google account already. The app doesn't need to be installed for the device to be found. For your specific case, [Google Account Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6160491) mentioned this: "*If you used your lost phone for 2-step verification, you must have a [backup phone](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1188780) or [backup code](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1187538).*"